# How should I organize source control for Android projects including libraries?

Tags: android, git, version-control, github, project-organization

I need a little help figuring out the best way (or best practice) to organize my Android project. For simplicity sake, let's say my Eclipse workspace for Android is `C:\Android\Projects\`. Inside that folder I like to separated applications from libraries and I have two other folders, `C:\Android\Projects\Applications` and `C:\Android\Projects\Components`.

For one project I have cloned a library from GitHub into the `Components` folder, let's say `C:\Android\Projects\Componentes\SampleLib` (inside that folder there's two folders `TheLib` and `TheLibExample`). And my app is created into `C:\Android\Projects\Applications\MyTestApp`. Then I included the library into the app by following [these instructions](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject).

Now let's say I want to use GitHub to share my app with the open-source community. I'll create a repository and push everything from `C:\Android\Projects\Applications\MyTestApp` into some repository.

If someone wants to fork my app or even help me, it will need the library to compile and run it, which is not included in my project itself. The `default.properties` file will have something like `android.library.reference.1=../Components/SampleLib/TheLib` and that someone will need to manually clone that library too and he would need to place it in the same relative path, otherwise it would mess up source control for my app.

The only way I can think of solving this issue is to organize my workspace like this:

```
C:\Android\Projects\Applications\MyTestApp\TheApp
C:\Android\Projects\Applications\MyTestApp\TheLib
C:\Android\Projects\Componentes\SampleLib
```

And my repository should be filled with the contents from `C:\Android\Projects\Applications\MyTestApp\`.

But what happens when the library is updated? I can't simply pull the new changes, I need to copy those into `TheLib` folder. In the previous folder organization this would not be needed as I was referencing the original cloned repository and not a copy.

What should I do then? Should I go with option one and let anyone forking my project deal with the library dependency as they see fit, or should I go with the second one and give everyone more work by keeping two folders in sync when the original one pulls changes from the it's repository?

Comment: how u resolved this issue for bitbucket ? bitbucket not adding my library in project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe git submodules will solve your issue.

Comment: A little confusing to use those. I'll have to dig deeper in the future, for now I'm just leaving things as they are. But I guess submodules is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Git submodules are very confusing and in my opinion too complicated for your case. From what I've read submodules are recommended when you want to include a 3rd party library, which you'll update rarely (that is only when there's another release). They don't work well with your own library, which you would update often. You might want to try git subtree instead: http://apenwarr.ca/log/?m=200904#30

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think Android's library project is a FAIL design. It is ridiculous that the only way I want refer/use other piece of code is to get another entire project and set everything up at IDE configuration level. what is a library? it should be a reusable component compiled and packaged in a archive format. According to their important note [Library project storage location](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html), I don't think there is a easy workaround that we can break the tie and manage the library as a real library. If your library is not so androidized, try to write/build is as a plain jar library and use maven manage the jar library build/release and project dependencies.

Hmmm, it is reasonable that google call it Android Library **Project**, not Android **Library**.

Comment: I agree with you on the whole setup of another project. Coming from Windows/C# where can I just reference a .dll file and now I can't do something similar in Android. Still, your answer doesn't really answer my question. And the library is not mine, it's someone else's. I honestly don't know what Maven is and can't be bothered to learn something new at the moment.

Comment: I know this is not an answer, I was trying to add it as a comment but size overflowed :P

Comment: There is a very important difference between an Android Library Project and a library you know from Java, where you just have a jar. The difference is the Library Project is not just copied into the main project. To save disc size only the used parts are copied and compiled into the main project. Also the resources can be changed easily in the main project, as they just replace the library stuff. Perfect for white label apps! If you don't like that, you still can develop a library and add it as a jar to your project. Please don't compare an apple with a banana!

Answer (score 1):

I personnaly think that git submodules don't entirely provide a very easy to use and powerful system for library dependencies.

Git subtrees are a better alternative. I found [a very useful guide](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/subtree-merging-and-you/) that explains how to do that.

Basically you can create a subfolder containing your dependencies, and clone repositories inside that subfolder:

```
$ mkdir vendor
$ git remote add -f ABS https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock
$ git merge -s ours --no-commit ABS/master
$ git read-tree --prefix=vendor/ABS/ -u ABS/master
$ git commit -m "Merged ABS into vendor/ABS/"
# Now another lib
$ git remote add -f Crouton https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton
$ git merge -s ours --no-commit Crouton/master
$ git read-tree --prefix=vendor/Crouton/ -u Crouton/master
$ git commit -m "Merged Crouton into vendor/Crouton/"
```

Then, you'll have the in this example two repos/libs inside `vendor/`; you just need to add them to your IDE/build system.

Git branching and modifications are much easier and more straightforward than with submodules.

I've even created [a small script](http://pastebin.com/hi8CYYsi) that automates this process for a list of libs.